# How I get two column from @OneToMany annotated field

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a class which has a tree structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ttp")
public class Ttp {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String name;
    private int position;
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Long parentId;
    //private Map<Long,Integer> childsMap;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="parent_ttp",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Ttp parent;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="parent_ttp",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Ttp> childs= new ArrayList<Ttp>();

    public Ttp(String name, Ttp parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Ttp() {

    }
...getters and setters
```

when I get **parentId** it work good becouse I get only Id parent without class.
How do I get the values of IDs and position properties of **childs** in List or HashMap, without loading objects completely?

p.s. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong. There is no need for a join table when modeling a `@OneToMany` relation. Try something like this, this is the simplest way and build upon it if you need something more complex

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ttp")
public class Ttp {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private int position;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ttp")
    private Ttp parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Ttp> children = new ArrayList<Ttp>();

    public Ttp(String name, Ttp parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public Ttp() {

    }
...getters and setters
```